# when I run a remoteapp from the RD Web interface 2012 r2 I get prompted to save or open this remote app

Tags: remoteapp, rdweb

I have Just setup RD Web Access with remote apps on server 2012 r2
when I log in to the rd web interface and select a remote app to run it ask me do I want save or open the remote app instead of just running
How do stop this

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

To prevent this from happening you MUST use Internet Explorer as your web browser, and you have to enable the RDS ActiveX control when prompted after visiting the remote web access site for the first time.

If you want to avoid the Remote App web site, see here for some other ideas for deploying remote app for your users: https://www.concurrency.com/blog/w/how-to-deliver-remoteapps-from-windows-server-2012

It's a little outdated, but it will give you some ideas.

Comment: Edge apparently also integrates RDP launching now (this may be specific to a beta build of 1707 but I noticed it working last week).